# resultado da divisão decimal

Tags: c, double

eu pesquisei aqui no fórum e vi perguntas similares, mas não consegui resolver o problema.

Exercício: "Implemente uma calculadora. O programa deve pedir 3 números ao usuário: 'a', 'b' e 'operação'. Se 'operação' for igual a 1, você deverá imprimir a soma de 'a + b'. Se ela for 2, a subtração. se for 3, a multiplicação. Se for 4, a divisão."

Eu já declarei 'a', 'b' e 'resultado' todos como double, como float, como int, e nunca da certo.

O código está assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    int a;
    int b;
    int operacao;
    double resultado;
    printf("ESCOLHA DOIS NUMEROS E A OPERACAO QUE SERA FEITA ENTRE 
            ELES\n");
    printf("ESCOLHA O NUMERO A\n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("ESCOLHA O NUMERO B\n");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    printf("ESCOLHA A OPERACAO\n");
    printf(" 1 = SOMA\n 2 = SUBTRACAO\n 3 = MULTIPLICACAO\n 4 = 
           DIVISAO\n");
    scanf("%d", &operacao);
    if(operacao == 1){
        resultado = a + b;
        printf("\n%d + %d = %.2f\n", a, b, resultado);
    }else{
        if(operacao == 2){
            resultado = a - b;
            printf("\n%d - %d = %.2f\n", a, b, resultado);
        }
        if(operacao == 3){
            resultado = a * b;
            printf("\n%d X %d = %.2f\n", a, b, resultado);
        }
        if(operacao == 4){
            resultado = (double)(a / b);
            printf("\n%d / %d = %.2f\n", a, b, resultado);
 }  }  }
```

Nesse formato ele funciona perfeitamente quando o resultado é um número inteiro, mas quando o resultado é decimal só aparecem zeros depois da virgula.

Quando eu declarei as variáveis como double ou float o programa só imprimia zeros...

Desculpa se essa pergunta é muito recorrente, mas eu realmente não consegui, e já olhei todas as respostas que poderiam me ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa converter os números para `double` antes da divisão, em seu exemplo você divide os inteiros e somente depois faz a conversão:

```
resultado = (double)(a / b);
```

Para corrigir e ter um número com decimais, basta converter um dos números antes da divisão, exemplo:

```
resultado = (double)a / b;
```

Com isso sua divisão já terá um resultado `double`, contendo decimais.

---

Um ponto do seu código que pode ser melhorado é a verificação da operação, caso ela seja diferente de `1`, você faz outros três `ifs`.

Aqui podemos utilizar o `else if`:

```
if(operacao == 1){
    resultado = a + b;
    printf("\n%d + %d = %.2f\n", a, b, resultado);
}
else if(operacao == 2){
    resultado = a - b;
    printf("\n%d - %d = %.2f\n", a, b, resultado);
}
else if(operacao == 3){
    resultado = a * b;
    printf("\n%d X %d = %.2f\n", a, b, resultado);
}
else if(operacao == 4){
    resultado = (double)a / b;
    printf("\n%d / %d = %.2f\n", a, b, resultado);
}
```

Ou um `switch`:

```
switch(operacao) {
  case 1: {
      resultado = a + b;
      printf("\n%d + %d = %.2f\n", a, b, resultado);
      break;
  }
  case 2: {
      resultado = a - b;
      printf("\n%d - %d = %.2f\n", a, b, resultado);
      break;
  }
  case 3: {
      resultado = a * b;
      printf("\n%d X %d = %.2f\n", a, b, resultado);
      break;
  }
  case 4: {
      resultado = (double)a / b;
      printf("\n%d / %d = %.2f\n", a, b, resultado);
      break;
  }
}
```

---

Seu código completo ficará mais ou menos da seguinte forma:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int a;
    int b;
    int operacao;
    double resultado;

    printf("ESCOLHA DOIS NUMEROS E A OPERACAO QUE SERA FEITA ENTRE ELES\n");
    printf("ESCOLHA O NUMERO A\n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("ESCOLHA O NUMERO B\n");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    printf("ESCOLHA A OPERACAO\n");
    printf(" 1 = SOMA\n 2 = SUBTRACAO\n 3 = MULTIPLICACAO\n 4 = DIVISAO\n");
    scanf("%d", &operacao);

    if(operacao == 1){
        resultado = a + b;
        printf("\n%d + %d = %.2f\n", a, b, resultado);
    }
    else if(operacao == 2){
        resultado = a - b;
        printf("\n%d - %d = %.2f\n", a, b, resultado);
    }
    else if(operacao == 3){
        resultado = a * b;
        printf("\n%d X %d = %.2f\n", a, b, resultado);
    }
    else if(operacao == 4){
        resultado = (double)a / b;
        printf("\n%d / %d = %.2f\n", a, b, resultado);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

> Veja online: https://repl.it/@Dadinel/ConsciousHospitableBooleanvalue

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado!

Comment: O meu erro era que quando anteriormente eu declarei eles como double eu não coloquei o scanf %lf correspondente, ai não ia :@

Comment: Realmente achei estranho não funcionar com todas as variáveis sendo ```double```, depurar ou exibir os valores no console ajuda muito nesses casos! :D