# Calculadora em C não retorna números decimais, ao dividir 7/2 ele me retorna 3. E como faço para o código voltar ao menu escolha?

Tags: c

Já tentei usar alguns outros tópicos aqui mas infelizmente não resolveram meu problema. O máximo que consegui foi mostrar 3.00 usando float, mas acho que não o usei corretamente. Sempre que divido nunca me retorna numero decimal, por exemplo 7/2 = 3 ou 10/3 = 3.
E outro problema, como faço para que o meu código ao invés de encerrar a execução volte novamente ao menu "escolha uma operação"?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>
int soma (int s1, int s2)
{
int resultado;
resultado = s1+s2;
return(resultado);
}

int subtracao (int sub1, int sub2)
{
int resultado;
resultado = sub1-sub2;
return (resultado);
}

int multiplicacao (int m1, int m2)
{
int resultado;
resultado = m1*m2;
return (resultado);
}

int divisao (int d1, int d2)
{
int resultado;
if (d1==0 && d2==0){
printf ("Nao é possivel dividir por zero!");
}
else{
resultado = d1/d2;
}
return (resultado);
}

int fatorial (int numfat)
{
int resultado, fat;
resultado=1;
for (fat=1;fat<=numfat;fat++)
{
resultado=resultado*fat;
}
return (resultado);
}

int potencia (int base, int exp)
{
int resultado;
if (exp==0)
return 1;
else if (exp==1)
return base;

return resultado=base*potencia(base, exp-1);
}

int main (void)
{

int op, num1, num2, numfato, bas, expo, resultado;

printf ("\n1 - Adicao (+)\n");
printf ("2 - Subtracao (-)\n");
printf ("3 - Multiplicacao (*)\n");
printf ("4 - Divisao (/)\n");
printf ("5 - Fatoral (!)\n");
printf ("6 - Potenciacao (^)\n");
printf ("\nEscolha a operacao que sera realizada:\n");

scanf ("%d", &op);
system("cls");

switch (op){
case 1:
printf ("Operacao escolhida > ADICAO\n");
printf ("Insira o primeiro numero:\n");
scanf ("%d", &num1);
printf ("Insira o segundo numero:\n");
scanf ("%d", &num2);
resultado=soma(num1, num2);
printf ("Resultado da operacao: %d\n", resultado);
break;

case 2:
printf ("O peracao escolhida > SUBTRACAO\n");
printf ("Insira o primeiro numero:\n");
scanf ("%d", &num1);
printf ("Insira o segundo numero:\n");
scanf ("%d", &num2);
resultado=subtracao(num1, num2);
printf ("Resultado da operacao: %d\n", resultado);
break;

case 3:
printf ("Operacao escolhida > MULTIPLICACAO\n");
printf ("Insira o primeiro numero:\n");
scanf ("%d", &num1);
printf ("Insira o segundo numero:\n");
scanf ("%d", &num2);
resultado=multiplicacao(num1, num2);
printf ("Resultado da operacao: %d\n", resultado);
break;

case 4:
printf ("Operacao escolhida > DIVISAO\n");
printf ("Insira o primeiro numero:\n");
scanf ("%d", &num1);
printf ("Insira o segundo numero:\n");
scanf ("%d", &num2);
resultado=divisao(num1, num2);
printf ("Resultado da operacao: %d\n", resultado);
break;

case 5:
printf ("Operacao escolhida > FATORIAL\n");
printf ("Insira o numero a ter sua fatorial calculada:\n");
scanf("%d", &numfato);
resultado=fatorial(numfato);
printf ("Resultado da operacao: %d\n", resultado);
break;

case 6:
printf ("Operacao escolhida > POTENCIACAO\n");
printf ("Insira a base:\n");
scanf ("%d", &bas);
printf ("Insira o expoente:\n");
scanf ("%d", &expo);
resultado=potencia(bas,expo);
printf("Resultado da operacao: %d\n", resultado);
break;

default:
printf ("OPCAO INVALIDA\n");
}

getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: A divisão de dois `int`'s resulta em outro `int` (com arredondamento "automático"). Se quer as casas decimais, tem que mudar tudo pra `float` ou `double`: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/453132/112052

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [resultado da divisão decimal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/453132/resultado-da-divis%c3%a3o-decimal)

Answer (score 0):

Você tem duas situações aqui:
Para retornar para o menu no fim da operação você pode usar o `goto`. Com ele você vai dizer para o seu programa que, quando chegar em determinado ponto, ele irá retornar para um ponto que você definiu no seu programa.
Exemplo:

Primeiro você indica a que ponto do programa deseja retornar, colocando uma identificação seguida por :

```
menu:
printf ("\n1 - Adicao (+)\n");
printf ("2 - Subtracao (-)\n");
```

E depois, onde você deseja que seja chamado novamente o menu você insere `goto menu`. No seu caso seria após exibir o resultado de cada operação.

Seu segundo problema, o da divisão, é que sempre que você trabalha a divisão de dois int ela irá retornar um número inteiro, portanto você precisa mudar seu código para double ou float, tanto no bloco de divisão quanto para exibir o resultado.

Exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    float resultado,a,b;
    a=7;
    b=3;
    numero = a/b;
    printf("O resultado e':%.2f \n\n",resultado);
}
```

Comment: `goto`? não poderia usar algo melhor como para controlar o fluxo do programa, um `while` por exemplo?

Comment: Usar o goto vai ser mais fácil de fazer, menos complicado de ler e não vai ter impacto na performance, além do que pela pergunta ele está começando, então por que não usar?

Comment: bem sugiro ler essa pergunta: [Por que o uso de GOTO é considerado ruim?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/20660/por-que-o-uso-de-goto-%c3%a9-considerado-ruim), eu não indicaria para alguém que está começando aprender goto, vale muito mais a pena aprender a usar for/while/etc

Comment: No link que você mesmo mandou diz (não só nessa parte, como em várias) que não é ruim se usado com moderação. "Cuide de sua saúde e use um pouquinho, bem pouquinho de goto, sempre que ele beneficiar mais do que atrapalhar." E é o caso. Mas é só uma opção de resposta, coloque outra ai e deixa ele testar as duas, vai ajudar mais ele a aprender do que ficar debatendo comigo aqui...

Comment: Tanto que até editei minha resposta de "precisa" para "pode" pois me expressei mal. Mas pra quem está começando essa discussão nos comentários é menos producente do que você colocar mais uma resposta ali pra ele. O problema do goto é mais a má fama por ser usado em excesso em códigos do que por ser realmente ruim.